# Rails selecting records from database based on attribute of has_one relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my database, all notices `have_one :active_comment_relationship`. However, not all of those `:active_comment_relationships` have a non-nil `commentee_id`, because not all notices have a supernotice.

notice.rb:

```
has_one  :active_comment_relationship, class_name: "Commentrelationship",
                                       foreign_key: "commenter_id",
                                       dependent: :destroy
has_one  :supernotice, through: :active_comment_relationship, source: :commentee
```

I want to select all notices from the database that have a nil `commentee_id`. Naively, I though something like this would work:

```
Notice.where('active_comment_relationship.commentee_id IS NULL')
```

But that would be far too easy wouldn't it? We couldn't have that. No, it looks like we have to suffer the misery of a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
find_by_sql(" SELECT     *
              FROM       notices
              LEFT JOIN  commentrelationships
              ON         notices.id = commentrelationships.commenter_id
              WHERE      commentrelationships.id IS NULL
              AND        commentrelationships.commentee_id IS NULL
           ; ")
```

But of course this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your desired result

```
 Notice.joins('left join commentrelationships ON notices.id = commentrelationships.commenter_id').where('commentrelationships.commentee_id IS NULL')
```

which according to the query is those notices which dont have `active_comment_relationship`